# After 5 minutes of running , my libgdx game crashes and turns red

Tags: android, libgdx

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen{

    Stage stage;

    LabelStyle style;
    BitmapFont font;

    TextureAtlas backbuttonatlas;
    TextButtonStyle backbuttonstyle;
    TextButton backbutton;
    Skin backskin;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture pibe;
    Sprite sprite;
    Vector2 position;
    Game game;

    Texture texture;

    public PlayScreen(Game game){
        this.game=game;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

    stage=new Stage();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W))
    {
        position.x+=5f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))
    {
        position.y-=5f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S))
    {
        position.x-=5f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))
    {
        position.y+=5f;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()==true)
    {
        if(Gdx.input.getY()>Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)
        {
        position.x-=5;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.getY()<Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)
        {
            position.x+=5;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.getX()>Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)
        {
            position.y+=5;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.getX()<Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)
        {
            position.y-=5;
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK))
        {
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
        }
    }

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);
    style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);

    backskin = new Skin();
    backbuttonatlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons/backbutton.pack");
    backskin.addRegions(backbuttonatlas);

    backbuttonstyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    backbuttonstyle.up = backskin.getDrawable("backbutton");
    backbuttonstyle.over = backskin.getDrawable("backbuttonpressed");
    backbuttonstyle.down = backskin.getDrawable("backbuttonpressed");
    backbuttonstyle.font = font;

    backbutton = new TextButton("", backbuttonstyle);
    backbutton.setWidth((float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8));
    backbutton.setHeight((float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8));
    backbutton.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20), (float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8)));

    backbutton.addListener(new InputListener(){

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int backbutton) {
                game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
            return true;
        };});

    batch=new SpriteBatch();

    stage.addActor(backbutton);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(pibe,(position.y/2-pibe.getWidth()/2),(position.x/2-pibe.getHeight()/2));
    batch.end();

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        texture = new Texture("cielo.png");

        pibe = new Texture("superman (100x52).jpg");
        position = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

> My LibGDX Game, collapse after a few minutes and I don't know why. I have read a little about the problem, and it says that the solution is to "dispose" the bitmapfont, or something like that. I'm new in LibGDX and I don't understand so much. A full explanation is appreciated. Sorry for my poor English.
>   This is the Play Class. Please, need help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the downvote on someone who clearly needs help with their code. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to put your "creating" stuff like `batch = new SpriteBatch()` inside

@Override
    public void create() {

)

you create billions of SpriteBatches that causes a memory issue.

Comment: Agreed. The OP is almost certainly maxing out the heap very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Render is called each time the device is ready to update the screen. You are creating new objects each frame. Some of them must be disposed of manually, which means calling the `.dispose()` method of that object.

call

```
font.dispose();
```

when you are finished with the font to prevent it eating up all the memory.

Ideally you'd want to create that font outside of the render loop.

You should create your objects in the constructor, so that they are not recreated every single frame. Unless of course that is intended behavior.

Try something like this

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen{

    Stage stage;

    LabelStyle style;
    BitmapFont font;

    TextureAtlas backbuttonatlas;
    TextButtonStyle backbuttonstyle;
    TextButton backbutton;
    Skin backskin;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture pibe;
    Sprite sprite;
    Vector2 position;
    Game game;

    Texture texture;

    public PlayScreen(Game game){
        this.game=game;
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);
        style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);
        stage=new Stage();
        backskin = new Skin();
        backbuttonatlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons/backbutton.pack");
        backskin.addRegions(backbuttonatlas);

        backbuttonstyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        backbuttonstyle.up = backskin.getDrawable("backbutton");
        backbuttonstyle.over = backskin.getDrawable("backbuttonpressed");
        backbuttonstyle.down = backskin.getDrawable("backbuttonpressed");
        backbuttonstyle.font = font;

        backbutton = new TextButton("", backbuttonstyle);
        backbutton.setWidth((float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8));
        backbutton.setHeight((float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8));
        backbutton.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20), (float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8)));

        backbutton.addListener(new InputListener(){

            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int backbutton) {
                    game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
                return true;
            };});

        batch=new SpriteBatch();

        stage.addActor(backbutton);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W))
        {
            position.x+=5f;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))
        {
            position.y-=5f;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S))
        {
            position.x-=5f;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))
        {
            position.y+=5f;
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()==true)
        {
            if(Gdx.input.getY()>Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)
            {
            position.x-=5;
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getY()<Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)
            {
                position.x+=5;
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getX()>Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)
            {
                position.y+=5;
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getX()<Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)
            {
                position.y-=5;
            }

            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK))
            {
                game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
            }
        }

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.draw(pibe,(position.y/2-pibe.getWidth()/2),(position.x/2-pibe.getHeight()/2));
        batch.end();

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        texture = new Texture("cielo.png");

        pibe = new Texture("superman (100x52).jpg");
        position = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Comment: Hi. First, thnks for aswering. When I move all the creation of the objects to the constructor, it asks me to change from: `public PlayScreen( Game game)`. To `public PlayScreen(final Game game)`. What should I do?. Also, if I move those objets, I have a problem with the: `stage.addActor(backbutton);`. It says: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"...